# Ionic 2: ionic serve resulting in white/blank page

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I have installed Ionic2 today and tried several starter projects. Each time ionic serve gives a blank (white) browser screen with no build or console errors. No edits have been made to the starter code.

app.bundle.js is truncated:

```
> (function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof
> require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return
> i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw
> f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var
> l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var
> n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return
> n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var
> o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return
> s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
> 
> },{}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
> arguments[4][1][0].apply(exports,arguments) },{"dup":1}]},{},[1,2])
> 
> //# sourceMappingURL=app.bundle.js.map
```

And app.bundle.js.map (first part) as follows:

```
> {"version":3,"sources":["../../../../Documents/Apps/ionic2/testapp/node_modules/browser-pack/_prelude.js","app/app.ts"],"names":[],"mappings":"AAAA;ACAA","file":"app.bundle.js","sourceRoot":"../../../","sourcesContent":["(function
> e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof
> require==\"function\"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return
> i(o,!0);var f=new Error(\"Cannot find module '\"+o+\"'\");throw
> f.code=\"MODULE_NOT_FOUND\",f}var
> l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var
> n=t[o][1][e];
```

There are several other threads relating to 'white screens' but no solution found so far reflects my scenario.

```
> Ionic info:
> 
> Cordova CLI: 6.3.0 Gulp version: CLI version 3.9.0 Gulp local: Local
> version 3.9.1 Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10 Ionic CLI
> Version: 2.0.0-beta.35 Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.19 OS:
> Windows 7 SP1 Node Version: v5.12.0
```

Solutions tried to date based on other posts:
- uninstall/reinstall ionic2 and cordova
- reinstall node.js
- running command prompt as administrator

Note: ionic serve working for older ionic1 projects.

Thanks for any insights.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found the solution for anyone else who comes across this problem.

On speculation I moved my App folder further up the directory tree (thinking it might be a path length issue for the node_module files. With my App folder now running c:\Apps apps are compiling and showing in the browser.

Comment: Please specify the correct path. Now my app is in the path C:\Users\test\ionic_app\myApp.To which folder I will move this app?

Comment: Here is my node path C:\Program Files\nodejs